# making a button with transparent background and different icons

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I am new to styles sheets. I want to make a button like this on my form.

[image]

How can I achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<button class='myBtn'>
  <svg></svg> // here should be an svg get it from the internet
  <span>Clear Selections<span>
</button>
.myBtn {
 display: flex;
 border: 1px solid gray;
 color: black;
 background: ; // ur color here
}
```

Also try to make a research before posting such questions

Answer (score 0):

When you want to do something basic in HTML/CSS, there are often multiple ways to do so.  Here's one simple solution using "flexbox" styles:

```
<div style="display: flex">
  <img src="yourIcon.png"/>
  <span>Clear Selections</span>
</div>
```

You could also use the `float` style, `position: absolute`-based styles, etc.